# Можно ли в WinForms сделать полупрозрачным контрол?

Tags: c#

Можно ли в WinForms сделать полупрозрачным контрол?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе контрола попробуйте прописать:

```
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Можете ещё переопределить отрисовку в методе OnPaint.